# bash scripts not loading any of ~/.bash*

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, bashrc, .bash-profile

Context:

- M1 MacBook
- macOS Ventura 13.5.2
- zsh as default shell
- GNU coreutils installed by homebrew
- `/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` added to path in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_login`

I have bash scripts that

- start with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
- invoke `date` with parameters that work with GNU date (`/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin`) but not macOS date (`/bin/date`)
- fail when invoked interactively from zsh because the wrong `date` is invoked

  - this isn't a guess, I checked with `which date` and `echo $PATH` and so on
  - it works if I run bash interactively first, and then invoke the script from bash rather than zsh

This looks like the path changes in `~/.bash*` are not being loaded when zsh launches my scripts.

To confirm that, **I added lines like `echo ".bashrc"` to each of `~/.bash*`, and none of those messages appear when I run my scripts.**

In zsh, `which bash` gives `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`, and `bash --version` starts with `GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0)`

**How do I get bash to load its configuration for scripts?**

Comment: Check `which date` in both contexts.

Comment: You really think I posted this without doing that?  You think that would affect whether or not the echos in .bash* would run?

Comment: No, but if you did that, it would have been nice to include the results in your post. Didn't you point to `date` as the reason why it fails?

Comment: Sure, and I could include a transcript of everything I've done in the last few hours to fix it, and the URLS of every search result that turned out not to help, and you'd still find a way to assume that I don't actually know what the problem is

Comment: I can't help you with such an attitude.

Comment: This kind of hostility to being helpful is why I rarely post here.  Some of y'all are very eager to respond but act like customer support who can only go through the list of the most obvious possibilities, and if anything it's more frustrating here because I know at least some of you know better.  It makes sense that useful answers are less prolific, but it sucks to get responses that ignore the actual question and assume I haven't done things I couldn't have arrived at the question I posted without having done

Comment: A lot of questions around here are resolved by helping the OP realize a troubleshooting step they missed. So asking things like @harrymc did is a very effective strategy. If you want to head off followup questions like that, you simply must put that information in your original writeup, otherwise we can't be sure you didn't just overlook something obvious like that. Consider reviewing ESR's [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the following section of the manual: [*6.2 Bash Startup Files*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). It describes what files get sourced, depending on the way of invoking `bash`. When `bash` interprets a script, it does not source anything automatically. Your options:

1. Run `bash` as interactive and/or a login shell. There will be side effects, so I don't really recommend this.
2. Explicitly source the desired file(s) in each script you want to affect.
3. Create an executable wrapper that sources some file and then `exec`s to `bash`. A quick and dirty example is:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   . /path/to/file
   exec /path/to/bash "$@"
   ```

   A script that wants to use the wrapper has to specify it in its shebang (instead of `bash`). Note the sourced `file` is interpreted by the shell interpreting the wrapper (`/bin/sh` in the example) and it cannot directly change the configuration of `bash` that starts later; for this `bash` it can only change things that get inherited, e.g. `PATH` in the environment.

   By choosing `bash` or the wrapper in the shebang of a script, you decide if the script is interpreted by vanilla `bash` or the "configured" one.
4. Use `BASH_ENV`:

> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the `PATH` variable is not used to search for the filename.

It seems this last method is what you think you want. Make it so the environment of your Zsh* contains `BASH_ENV` and the value of the variable is the full path of some config file for Bash. The config file may be

- some standard file (e.g your `.bashrc`),
- or a custom file that sources one or more standard files,
- or a dedicated custom file that only changes `PATH`,
- or a custom file that does whatever you want.

Notes:

- Files like `.bashrc` may contain code not designed to be sourced when Bash interprets a script (as they normally don't get sourced in such case), so a dedicated custom file that *only* changes `PATH` seems a good idea.
- `BASH_ENV` in the environment will affect any script interpreted by `bash` and any `bash -c` invocation. Scripts calling scripts may cause the effect(s) of your custom file to pile up. Consider placing `unset BASH_ENV` in the custom file.
- A hybrid approach is possible. E.g. this wrapper:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  BASH_ENV=/path/to/custom_file exec /path/to/bash "$@"
  ```

  will make `bash` (not `sh`) source the `custom_file`. This may be considered an improvement with respect to the previously introduced wrapper. When using this (or the other) wrapper, you don't need `BASH_ENV` in the environment of your Zsh. More: if you want to be able to easily run vanilla `bash` then you don't *want* `BASH_ENV` in the environment of your Zsh.

---

* There should be a way to add the variable to the environment of your desktop or whatever (i.e. not only Zsh), but I don't know macOS and I cannot guide you in detail.

Comment: I guess I misremembered that it would set `BASH_EXECUTION_STRING` so my config could adapt; is there something analogous to `BASH_EXECUTION_STRING` I can use to detect when bash was invoked for a `#!`?